# How to force IE9 to render in IE9 Document Mode?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

My website does not display well on IE7. But I don't worry about this anyway. But IE9 users are saying that they can't see things well on their browsers too. When I click F12 and check their browsers, their IE9s are rendering in IE7 Document Mode. If I change to IE9 Document Mode it works perfect.

So I wonder, is there a way to force IE9 to render in IE9 document mode by putting some extra code or something. Those extra code should not affect other users with IE8 using the website.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need "edge" mode.

Check this out:

```
  <html>
   <head>
      <title>My Web Page</title>
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
   </head>
   <body>
      <p>Content goes here.</p>
   </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT Mennans answer is step one to resolve the problem but also check this option:

IE users also may have a setting like "always display intranet pages in compatibility mode" checked.

Comment: I think Mennan answer sorted the problem .. the website is on testing server inside LAN though. Thanks for the help.